# polylang custom product attributes

Tags: attributes, product, polylang

Is it possible to translate custom product attributes using Polylang Pro?

I don't see anywhere the option to translate a custom product attribute.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came from the Polylang!
I need to unsychronize the Custom Product Attributes.

> The developper need to use the pllwc_copy_post_metas filter. It will
> allow you to uncopied and unsynchronized the *product_attribute and
> attribute* metas. Be careful because these 2 metas included custom and
> global attributes. That's mean the developper must target only the
> custom attributes inside this filter (that's required to get a fair
> knownledge of WooCommerce).
>
> The pllwc_copy_post_metas filter is documented in
> polylang-wc/include/product-language-cpt.php
>
> The developper may need to unhook the 3 actions in
> polylang-wc/products.php at line 30-33 to allow you to have global
> attributes in one language and custom product attributes in another.

```
add_filter("pllwc_copy_post_metas", function($to_copy, $sync, $from, $to, $lang){
    unset($to_copy['my_custom_product_attribute_name']);
    return $to_copy;
}, 1, 5);
```